# Wanting idiots guide to SSH

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04

Say you create an SSH key on host 1 and send the public part to host 2 so you can login from host 1 to host 2 without a password. If you then want to login from host 1 to a new host say host 3, what do you do?

Do you create a new key on host one and send that to host 3? Or will that mess up the relationship between host 1 and host 2? Or do you send the same public key to host 3?

I cant find a tutorial that explains what is going on simply enough for my brain to understand.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I expect this question will be closed".

Comment: I've removed the "I expect this question will be closed".

Comment: That doesn't really change the fact that you deliberately wasted everyone's time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: The very helpful @techraf in his answer below has helped me with a thing that has puzzled me for ages. Yes I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you then want to login from host 1 to a new host say host 3, what do you do?

If you want to:

- establish a new SSH session from `host 1` to `host 3`, you should add the public key of the user on `host 1`<sup>*</sup> to the `authorized_keys` file on `host 3`. Technically, it doesn't matter if it's the same key-pair as for `host 2`, or a different one.
- connect from `host 1` to `host 2` and from within that session to connect to `host 3`, you need to add the public key of the user on `host 1` (the same one which you use to connect to `host 2`) to the `authorized_keys` file on `host 3` and enable SSH agent forwarding in SSH daemon on `host 2` and add an option to use SSH agent forwarding when establishing a session from `host 1` to `host 2`.

---

<sup>*</sup> Strictly speaking "the public key of `host 1`" means the public key of the key-pair that `host 1` will use when connecting to the target. It can be the one in the default location `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or explicitly specified with `-i` when establishing a session, or specified in the configuration file.

Comment: So are you saying there can be multiple private keys per host? And that you can have several private keys on one host, and each key relates to specific remote hosts?

Comment: Yes, you can do either. You may use the same key for several hosts, or different key-pairs for different hosts. There are no technical limitations.

Comment: Also, it's not really 100% correct to use a shortcut phrase "host key", because you are probably referring to the key-pair stored under user's home directory, both: on source-host and target-host.

Comment: But if you have more than one key pair on your local host when you try to login to a remote host, how do you specify which pair to login using?

Comment: It's explained in the last paragraph of the answer, please read.

Comment: So there's a default key?

Comment: I did not use a phrase **default key** anywhere. I don't understand your question.

Comment: If you try to connect without specifying which key to use, it will prefer a specific key? Maybe the first one created? If you connect without using `-i`.

Comment: It will **be the one in the default location `~/.ssh/id_rsa`**. I have already written that in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. The key in the "default location" is the first one created yes?

Comment: No, it is not. **The key in the default location** is **the key in the default location** regardless how you create it, when you create it, or in which order. Default locations for keys are specified in the man page.

Comment: Oh ok. If there are no keys and you create the first key, does that go in the default location?

Comment: @NigelAlderton If you generate a key-pair using `ssh-keygen`, it will ask you for the key location (and provide a hint where it will store the key if you just pressed Enter). And yes, if you press Enter without reading the message, it will be the default location.

Answer (score 1):

> If you then want to login from host 1 to a new host say host 3, what
>   do you do?
>
> Do you create a new key on host one and send that to host 3?

No i don't

> Or will that mess up the relationship between host 1 and host 2?

Yes it will

> Or do you send the same public key to host 3?

Yes i do

---

Edit : a private key is used to identifies a single host to ensure its identity.

However, of course :

[How can multiple private keys be used with ssh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1962/how-can-multiple-private-keys-be-used-with-ssh)

[What is the best practice: separate ssh-key per host and user VS one ssh-key for all hosts?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40050/what-is-the-best-practice-separate-ssh-key-per-host-and-user-vs-one-ssh-key-for)

By the way, the common practice is `one host = one key`, so that you can revoke all at once if needed...For sure there is not a lot of place for granularity here, but depends on your security concerns.

Comment: So are you saying there's one private key per host? And if you create a new private key it will overwrite the old one and break all the relationships with other hosts?

Comment: "the common practice is one host = one key". Thank you.